# How can I increase a number in the middle of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this string:

```
string = ("book_volume_2")
```

and I want to increase that number to 3, 4 and so on, up to 6

I've tried

```
book = ("book_volume_")
book_plus = (book + str(book +1))
```

I get something like

```
book_volume_2book_volume22
```

but I'm expecting:

```
book_volume_3
```

Is there any way to obtain this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442460-increment-numbers-in-a-string/)?

Comment: `book + 1` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: You were right.

Comment: Your question is also vague. If you have `book1 = "book_vol_1"` When will you ever need to do `book1 + book1`? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string `string = "book_volume_2"` where the last character is a digit, then you can replace that with the next number like this:

```
def next_number(book):
    base = book[:-1]
    digit = int(book[-1])
    return base + str(digit + 1)

print(next_number('book_volume_2'))
```

Comment: This will break as soon as you get to double digit numbers

Comment: Well double digits are excluded since the OP says `and so on, up to 6`

Comment: True, but I think it's worth clarifying given the clearly low level of OPs understanding of this problem

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use are `f-strings`

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(f'book_volume_{i}')
```

I've applied the logic in a for-loop to show how it works.

But basically, whatever is inside the curly brackets is not considered a string.

e.g.

if I have function myFunc:

```
def myFunc():
    return 5
```

And then I do `print(f'book_volume_{myFunc()}')`

The result will be: `book_volume_5`

Comment: f-strings are not *necessary*.

Comment: It's not about necessary, it's the cleanest solution. New to Python3.7 you can also format it: `"book_volume_{}".format("5")` But python added f-strings for a reason. Clean code is best practice!

Comment: Your example with the f-string is wrong - you need to _call_ the function if you want the value. As it is, you'll get `book_volume_<function myFunc at 0x12345678>` (address is an example ofc).

Comment: I meant that the issue with OP's code wasn't the lack of string interpolation techniques. I don't disagree with your code itself of course.

Comment: @b_c my bad. I forgot to put parenthesis when calling `myFunc()`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes, the question is extremely misleading. I know he wants `f-strings` I'm not too sure how he wants to implement it though. The example should suffice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the numeric part of the string an integer if you want to increment it. Assuming the book name and number are always separated by an underscore you could do something like:

```
mystr = "book_volume_2"
book, sep, vol = mystr.rpartition('_')
vol = str(int(vol) + 1)
my_new_str = ''.join([book, sep, vol])

> 'book_volume_3'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string = "book_volume_" + input('Enter volume number: ')
print(string)
```